# How to load image in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have the following project structure and I'm trying to load an image into an image view. I've tried many ways but they all result in exceptions.

```
Project Folder
\----->src
     \----->main
          \----->java
               \----->com
                     ----->file.java
\----->images
     \----->products
```

Method that I've tried:

```
new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/products"))
new Image("/images/products")
new Image(getClass().getResource("/images/products"))
```

The project is a Maven project and the target folder looks like the image shown.
[image]

Comment: The last one should work (assuming `products` is a valid image file; it's probably better to make sure it has a sensible filename extension such as .png or .jpg). If it's not working the most likely thing is that your images folder is not being deployed along with the complied class files. Can you post the *output* folder from your project (probably called `build`, `bin`, or maybe `target`).

Comment: @James_D, thanks for responding I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I'm not convinced the `target` folder is actually your output folder: there do not appear to be any class files there, for a start. Where is `file.class` created?

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
URL url = new URL("/images/products/" + filename);
Image image = new Image(url.toString(), 100, 100, true, true);
```